# Can I change the application name in appxmanifest for a UWP app for different languages?

Tags: uwp, localization, appxmanifest

I know, I can add statements for different languages like this

```
<Resources>
    <Resource Language="en-us">
    <Resource Language="de-de">
</Resources>
```

But how can I give my app different names for different languages like "My US App" and my "My DE App"?

Thank you!

P.S. I found nothing in the net about this question. FYI, I don't use Visual Studio.

Comment: You may find [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/main/UWPSamples/System/NLSAndLocalizationUWP) useful.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using the localization mechanism of UWP. I noticed that you mentioned that you are not using VS. You might need to create so necessary files by yourself.

1. Create a `Strings` folder inside the Project folder.
2. Under `Strings`, create a new sub-folder and name it `en-US`. You could create other sub-folders like `de-DE` and `fr-FR` for different language.
3. Under `en-US`, create a new Resources File (.resw) and name it
   "Resources.resw". The Resources File (.resw) is a template in the Visual Studio. You need to create such file by yourself.
4. Add key-value data in the `Resources.resw` file for name. For example, the key is `AppDisplayName` and the value is `En-ValueTitle`.
5. Open your manifest file, under `Applications`-`uap:VisualElements` node, find `DisplayName` element and change its value as `ms-resource:AppDisplayName`.

Now your app will use the corresponding `AppDisplayName` value you defined in the `Resources.resw` file as the app name when you set the different default language for your app.

Here the `Resources.resw` file opened via notepad:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="metadata">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="assembly">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <data name="AppDisplayName" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>En-ValueTitle</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

I'll try this as soon as I'm back home.

Comment: @Thomas Have you tried it?

Comment: No, not yet. I’m currently very busy with another project. But today is father‘s day in Germany and I hope I’m able to try it today if no one is going to occupy me ;-). I’ll update this thread then.

Comment: Well, I spent a significant part of this holiday trying to get it running. No success.

Comment: @Thomas So where is the issue?

Comment: I created the resources.resw files as mentioned. They get installed in the Strings folder. I tried different locations (just below the app's folder and in the Resources folder). 

I changed the manifest file from within the MSIX packaging tool.

Trying to install from the created .msix file always says that it tries to install an app named "ms-resource:AppDisplayName".

Tools used:  Inno setup and the MSIX packaging tool to create the msix file for the MS Store.

I'm desperate. Please help!

Comment: @Thomas It seems the  resources.resw you created is not loaded correctly. Not sure if the issue is related to the location or the resources.resw file itself.  Maybe you could directly use the resources.resw file from the official sample to test https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/ApplicationResources/shared/strings.

Comment: @Thomas The best way is doing this in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! How can I use Visual Studio when I use Xojo for development?

Comment: @Thomas Just do the localization work in VS. Like creating a resources.resw file in the correct location and adding values. After you've done it, you can close VS and switch back to your development tool as usual.

Comment: @Thomas Any updates about your issue?

Comment: Sorry, no not yet. I'm still busy with other projects. But I promise, I'll keep you updated.